# MySQL database not receiving post variables from android in WampServer after reconfiguration

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, wamp

As a project, I created a MySQL database with PHPMyAdmin in WampServer. the particular table bus_location had 3 fields: Bus_Num, Latitude and Longitude these variables would be parsed in JSON and sent in post form to the database with the help of an accompanying PHP script. This would then be retrieved by another android application and placed on a map. Unfortunately, the PC configured for outside access to Wamp crashed and I had to reconfigure WampServer on a new machine. To my knowledge, everything is configured the same, although now, the data is not being placed in the database using POST as it was before. I can't figure out why I'll provide the PHP script as well as a screenshot of the table structure.

My partner working on the application side said his code hasn't been touched since we got this to work last spring. So I believe it is a slightly different database or PHP code. The PHP code is as follows

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$hostname = "localhost";
$database = "bus_times";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die ("connection failed.");
mysql_select_db($database) or die ("database selection failed");

// this script should receive two things: a location and the bus which sent the location. This query goes into the bus_location table, finds the row corresponding to the right bus, and overwrites the location 
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE bus_location SET Longitude=".$_POST['longitude']." WHERE Bus_Num=".$_POST['bus_num']. "AND Latitude=".$_POST['latitude']."");





if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {
echo 'Success.';
} else {
echo mysql_error();
}


mysql_close ();

?>

</body>
</html>
```

I apologize as I don't have my partners code for the application sending the post variables but he assures me that he didn't touch it since we got it working. I'm also fairly certain I created the same table since I took a screenshot before the machine crashed. I can't post an image of the table structure as my rep isn't high enough, but if anyone can at least try to point me in the right direction as to what can be wrong it would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you just print_r($_POST) and have the android device Log.v the results?

Comment: what is the return value? Try to change your $_POST[..] to $_GET[..] and test it from your browser with the get params and watch the result. Always try to debug it, and get as much output as you can

Comment: You could also do a curl from a linux bash to get output `curl --data "longitude=10&bus_num=66&latitude=22" http://example.com/yourphp.php`

Comment: the return value from the PHP script is an empty query although it was always like that since the Post variable would only use the script for a short while before placing it in the table

Comment: yeah but please try to get output

Comment: perhaps you only need and space before AND in
 `..WHERE Bus_Num=".$_POST['bus_num']. "AND..`

Answer (score 0):

I see several issues with your code:

1. **Don't directly put `POST` vars in your MySQL query**. This might be used as SQL injection and be a potential hijack door to your app. Always process your `$_POST` values prior to putting them into the `mysql_query()` command.
2. **Don't use `mysql_*` anymore**. Use the new interfaces for `MySQL`: a PDO or `MySQLi`, which fits better to your code.
3. It's hard to tell what's wrong just looking into this code, but possible issues are:

   - MySQL permissions: Try connecting to the database with the credentials you're using by hand.
   - Some PHP module not installed, like `php5-mysql`.
   - Some typo in the code.

Definitely, I'd try debug it using the CLI prior to using `POST` directly. If you don't have access to `CLI`, use `print_r()`, `echo`s as many as you need until you find the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Check the actual SQL text you are sending to the database, before you send it.  For debugging, you can use echo or printf or whatever. Check that the statement you are sending is what you really want to send.

```
$sql = "UPDATE bus_location SET Longitude=".$_POST['longitude']
       ." WHERE Bus_Num=".$_POST['bus_num']. " AND Latitude=".$_POST['latitude']."");
                                        //    ^
                                        //    |
                                        //    +--- add a space here
// for debugging
echo "<br><b>DEBUG: SQL=", $sql, "</b><br><br>";

$query = mysql_query($sql);
```

Divide and conquer. The SQL text is a convenient spot; because this is something you can test, whether the statement is right or not.

As Olvathar commented, looks like you want a space before the `AND` keyword. (If Bus_Num is numeric and has a value, MySQL will take the portion before the 'A', but then we'd expect that MySQL would throw a syntax error when it encountered `Latitude`.

---

Note: your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Consider what happens when the value of `$_POST['longitude']` is included in the SQL text and it contains:

```
'-81.6666 WHERE 1=1 -- '
```

Comment: I'll try that now. Bus_Num is of type int and length 1. My partners code is designed to take in the latitude and longitude values in as type text, encode them in JSON and send them I'm fairly sure I got the types correct since i took a screencap of the structure before the previous machine crashed. What I'm unsure about is whether I assigned it to auto increment as primary key or not. I was thinking that may cause an issue as my partner is sending a single integer within the post variable.